# How to create an archive dropdown menu

Tags: templating, datetime, archives

How do I create a dropdown menu that filters all the posts into month and year, and then link to a template that has the entries of that month and year displayed?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```html
<fieldset>
    {# Use the `group` filter to get the years, entries were posted in #}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog') %}
    {% set entriesByYear = entries|group('postDate|date("F Y")') %}
    <select name="year">
        {# Go through the `year` groups #}
        {% for year, entries in entriesByYear %}
            <option value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

I can get the month and year to display in a dropdown using the code I found above, now I just need to get those elements to link to the corresponding template file. I have my Route setup as 'blog/year/month' and a template setup as well.

Comment: The code in your example only outputs the year, but you stated that you're grouping by year and month; which is correct?